# replace any link

Tags: php

I have a news script in PHP i need the script to replace any link which it will be included within the news (links to other websites which the original news will be there ) i need the link for the website to be replace with click here instead , all the links will be replaced every time with click here

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you try and rephrase and perhaps give some examples?

Comment: If add in the command links example http  //  www. Yahoo . Com /go to links to replace this link to only (clik here )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url="http://google.com";
$url=preg_replace('@(http?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1">Click Here</a>', $url);
echo $url;//echoes <a href="http://google.com">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: he just want to replace text between <a> and </a> not the link URL itself. He wanted to hide the url on display.

Comment: the code does just that. it will replace `http://google.com` (or whatever url) with `<a href="http://google.com">Click Here</a>`